# Deforming a rubber ring

Tags: geometry, terminology

If you take a rubber ring (i.e. a torus) the size of a dinner plate or so say and say an inch or so thick, and you grip it with both hands at opposite ends and twist it with both hands, you can deform the ring into another shape, but an unstable one: it springs back at the slightest touch.

What is this shape called and how do you model it mathematically?

Just curious. I can't find any reference to it on the internet, but no doubt I'm not using the right search terms.

Comment: What direction are you twisting?

Comment: Metastable tori under tension? (Don't know, just a guess, in case it helps find references.)

Comment: Are you asking what the shape of the deformed torus is called? If so, then I doubt there is a special name, because the physical property of snapping back to to the rubber ring shape is not a property of the shape of the deformed torus. You could mould the thing so that it would always snap back to the deformed shape.

Comment: Thanks for these comments. I'm sorry I'm so vague in my description. I'm afraid I just don't have the vocabulary to be more explicit. What I'm really curious to know is the mathematics to show that this configuration is in unstable equiliberum.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/gold/pdfs/teaching/old_literature/Goriely2006.pdf) of interest for you ?

Comment: Oh yes it is! Thank you so much for this, Jean Marie. I shall study that carefully. Most grateful.